# How to parse DTO to Pojo objects

Tags: java, parsing, reflection, dto, pojo

Well, I'm trying to parse objects and I'm having so much issues.
My classes are like this:

-**Entidad**-

```
public class Entidad{

    private Long codEntidad;
    private Set<Comunicacion> comunicacion;


    /*------------ Getter and Setters --------------*/

}
```

-**Comunicacion**-

```
public class Comunicacion {

    private Entidad entidad;
    private Long codComunicacion;

    /*------------ Getter and Setters --------------*/

}
```

I need to parse to DTO objects:

-**EntidadDTO**-

```
public class EntidadDTO{

    private Long codEntidad;
    private Set<ComunicacionDTO> comunicacionDto;


    /*------------ Getter and Setters --------------*/

}
```

-**ComunicacionDTO**-

```
public class ComunicacionDTO {

    private EntidadDto entidadDto;
    private Long codComunicacion;

    /*------------ Getter and Setters --------------*/

}
```

I tried to use:

BeanUtils.copyProperties(entidad, entidadDto);

It seems that the parse is success but the property entidadDto.getComunicacionDto(); is a hashMap of Comunicacion (not ComunicacionDTO)

Should I try to make a custom parse with reflection?

Also I'd like to use this to parse more objects with a similar structure.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try dozer. You can define mappings from bean to bean using it.
http://dozer.sourceforge.net/

Comment: I've heard about Dozer, but really can convert objects with cyclic references like these?

Answer (score 0):

Why you want to parse java object and move data to other java object?
Parsing is for unstructured strings not for objects.

Use setters/getters to move data from one object to the other, using reflection will make you cry when you start doing refactorings.

Comment: The reason is that on my controller I create a DTO and via Service the Dao needs a Pojo to create a register on ddbb.
Should I change the controller to get a Pojo and forgot the Parse?